# React -Redux: Why is data not ready even if fetching is finished?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Currently I'm on my way to learn how to use fetching-Flags to retrieve asynchrouns data. The fetching flag works well. But even if `isFetching=false`, which means that the `profile` is not available. React gives me the error that it is undefined:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

**Header Component**

```
export class Header extends Component {
    

    render() {
        const { isAuthenticated } = this.props.auth;
        const profile = this.props.profile;
        const isFetching = this.props.isFetching


        console.log (isFetching)
        console.log (profile);
        


 //  Data is fetching
if (isFetching === true) return (<h1>Loading ...</h1>);

//  Data is ready: Here the username within the profile is called.
if (isFetching === false ) return (<h1> Hallo {profile[0].username} </h1>);

}
}



const loadingSelector = createLoadingSelector(['GET_USER', 'GET_PROFILE']);

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    const auth = state.auth
    const profile = state.profile
    const isFetching = loadingSelector(state)

  return { auth, profile, isFetching}
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { logout }
)(Header);
```

Profile Action

```
export const getProfile = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  // Profile Loading
  dispatch({ type: GET_PROFILE_REQUEST });
  dispatch(showLoading());
  axios
    .get(apiBase + "/profile/", tokenConfig(getState))
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data
      });
      dispatch(hideLoading())
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
      dispatch({
        type: GET_PROFILE_FAILURE,
      });
      dispatch(hideLoading())
    });
};
```

Profile Reducers

```
const initialState = {
  profile: null
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
case GET_PROFILE_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
      };
case GET_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        profile: action.payload,
      };

case GET_PROFILE_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        profile: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Console Log**: Before the fetching process starts the fetching flag is false while the profile is not ready.

```
header.js:16 false // isFetching
header.js:18 {profile: null}
header.js:16 true // isFetching
header.js:18 {profile: null}
header.js:16 true // isFetching
header.js:18 {profile: null}
header.js:16 false // isFetching
header.js:18 {profile: Array(1)}
```

Why is the data not ready (undefined), even if the fetching flag indicates that it should be available?

I'm happy for any clarification.

**Edit**
I have simplified my code-sinppet and added the Action Creator and Reducer. The action creator is called in App.js. I also think the error is caused due to the curcumstances that at the very beginning the `isFetching=false` (see console log) while the profile data is still `null`. Thus might causing the error.

But how do I account for this iniatial state in my component?

Comment: What is "data" in your code snippets? There is no `data` identifier. Is it possibly something in a reducer that is undefined? Please include action creators and reducer code. `Unhandled Rejection` usually means there is a Promise chain somewhere throwing a rejection that your code isn't handling via a `catch` block.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you. I added the code snippets you asked for. Data is in my case profile i clarified these in my post. I assume that the error is caused because in the very benning the is fetching flage is false (see console log)  while the profile is null. Thus jumping into the condional rendering for `if (isFetching=f==false) return({profile[0].username})` eventhough the `profile` is not null.  I wonder now how i can account for that case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initially the isFetching=false it returns a null object which you are trying to render it throws the error since the profile is not loaded yet if you can change your render part as shown below you can achive the required

```
  export class Header extends Component {


   render() {
    const { isAuthenticated } = this.props.auth;
    let profile=[]
    if(this.props.profile!==null){
     profile = this.props.profile;
     }
    const isFetching = this.props.isFetching


    console.log (isFetching)
    console.log (profile);
    



 if (isFetching === true) return (<h1>Loading ...</h1>);

 if (isFetching === false ) return 
 (<h1>
  Hallo {profile.length>1? 
 {profile[0].username}:null} </h1>); //initially it renders profile once it is available

 }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works. Is it possible to put the `{profile.length>1? 
 {profile[0].username}:null}` into the ` if`  function as additional condition so i have to do this check only a single time and not always whenever i want to access some data profile array?

Comment: the profile is null initially and then available you got to use it in above way unless you want to modify the initial state to true(state from redux)